# how to 'fix' the header footer position using jquery mobile with data-position="fixed"

Tags: header, jquery-mobile, footer, css-position

i am using jquery mobile and for header/footer i am using data-position="fixed".

However, when we scroll the page... the header footer goes away ands reappear when scrolling stops..
Is there a way we could just make it fixed on the screen an show all the time you are scrolling ?

I can only think of a way is to apply position fixed and not use jquerymobile for these elements..

Comment: I believe this is the expected behavior from jQM

Comment: This thread should shed some light on options as well as the direction the jQM team is taking on fixed.  https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/58

Comment: thats the expected behavior as Phill Pafford mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I tried my best to get this to work. If you want you can delete the function that changes the header and footer class from .ui-fixed-overlay to .ui-fixed-inline and remove the webkit animation from .fade.in and .fade.out, but I've had no lock preventing the windows from disappearing. However, I believe JQM only recalculates the position of the header and footer elements after you scroll.

I put the following css in page div to remove the webkit animation.

.ui-fixed-inline {
    opacity: 1!important;
    display:block!important;
    -webkit-animation-name:none!important;
}
.fade.in, .fade.out {
    opacity: 1!important;
    -webkit-animation-name:none!important;
    display:block!important;
}

I know this is not what you want but it does speed up the reappearance of the header and footer elements (it looks a bit choppy.) Unless you want to rewrite the JQM javascript that controls the header and footer positioning, I don't think there is any easy way to do this as the JQM fixed position code is built to re-position after the user scrolls. I'll keep looking and edit this answer if I find a way.

Comment: Sorry for the late response... just saw your answer... we ended up not using the data-position="fixed". however - i was about to try css for fixing the position, and not the data-role attribute. Will try to get some time out and see how your solution works... thanks so much for your time !!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of Chase's code works fine for me:

```
/* sass - remove toolbar fade */
.nofade{
 &.in, &.out {
    -webkit-animation-name:none;
 }
}
```

Note that tap-to-hide toolbars uses this same fade property, so the following is required:

```
$.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled false  # coffeescript
```