# jQuery Mobile - make fixed header not fade out when scrolling

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to have a fixed header for my jQuery Mobile project like this [demo page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html).

I've tried the attributes of data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true", however my header isn't visible as you scroll and then fades in. How can I remove this fade in / out functionally?

I have found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364227/how-to-fix-the-header-footer-position-using-jquery-mobile-with-data-position) but I think it might be outdated as although they discuss the issue they don't mention this demo page which seems to do what they need:

Comment: did you try changing CSS position of your header to fixed?

Comment: I had other issues with the header jumping around the page when I did it with my own CSS. Just updated my versions of JQM, seems to be working ok now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of JQuery Mobile are you using? The "True fixed toolbars" were added to the last version jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 Final. Check it at http://bit.ly/JjPmwo